# Start at the penultimate character in capture group of regex php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex that only captures between the second to last and last occurrences of the surrounding characters (if you get what I mean).

My regex so far is this:

`\[(.*?)]\{(.*?)\}/ig`

This is my string:

`[don't touch me] random text [touchme]{Secondcapturegroup}`

As you can see by this screenshot, it's capturing everything from `[don't` all the way to `[touchme`]. I want it to effectively ignore `[don't touch me] random text`

[image: don'ttouchme]

I'm still learning regex, but I know there must be something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character class that excludes the closing square bracket instead of using `.` (and in this way the non-greedy quantifier `*?` is no more needed)

```
\[([^]]*)]{([^}]*)}
```

In this way the attempt at the first opening square bracket will fail because the closing square bracket is not followed by an opening curly bracket.

With your pattern you obtain a wrong result because the regex engine parse your string from the left and try to succeed at each position (so the first position always win).

Note that the `i` modifier is useless.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! As for the `i` modifier, I know that's useless - but I completely forgot I had put it in there. I removed it now, for cleanliness sake